# Display content of JSP file in browser through Liferay Struts Action

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

How to display the content of jsp file in browser through Liferay Struts Action (DXP 7.1)? I use the execute method with parameters of HttpServletRequest and HtttpServletResponse, and place the jsp file in resources/META-INF/resources, but it is not showing in the browser, also no any errors in microservice logs.

The project, where I'm implementing new functionality, use Scala and SBT, so I can't use maven or something else.

I tried to follow the official documentation of overriding Liferay Struts action on their page, but it describe case for DXP 6.x version, despite this, I still tried the described approach using struts-config.xml, but it did not help.

The latest iteration of implementation based on of using requestDispatcher, but I'm not sure this is right:

```
class RedirectInfoAction extends BaseStrutsAction with LiferayLogSupport {

  override def execute(
    originalStrutsAction: StrutsAction,
    request: HttpServletRequest,
    response: HttpServletResponse
  ): String = {

    log.info("Strut action execution started...")

    getUserId(request) match {
      case Some(_) =>

        val servletContext = request.getSession().getServletContext

        val requestDispatcher = servletContext.getRequestDispatcher("/page.jsp")

        requestDispatcher.include(request, response)

      case None =>
        response.sendError(401, "The user is not authorized")
    }
    ""
  }
```

Comment: Can you show a [mcve] of your code? (e.g. please see [ask]) Also note: At some point in time, Liferay technically removed struts - and while there's some mentioning of struts left, that's just the bare minimum vocabulary that survived, not the full implementation. I'm not sure when exactly it happened. If it was already in 7.1, struts-config.xml wouldn't do much any more.

Comment: Updated post with latest implementation attempt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all depends on how you deploy the code: You're just posting the code here, but if you look at the [blade sample for a struts action](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-blade-samples/tree/7.1/liferay-workspace/extensions/struts-action), you'll see an additional critical part, which is the `@Component` section (granted, this requires using Java), as well as the `@Reference` to the servlet context.

You can also manually register such a service to the OSGi runtime, but that requires quite a lot of internal OSGi knowledge.

```
@Component(
    immediate = true, property = "path=/portal/blade",
    service = StrutsAction.class
)
public class BladeStrutsAction extends BaseStrutsAction {

    public String execute(
            HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
            HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse)
        throws Exception {

        RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher =
            _servletContext.getRequestDispatcher("/html/portal/blade.jsp");
        requestDispatcher.forward(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);

        return null;
    }

    @Reference(target = "(osgi.web.symbolicname=blade.strutsaction)")
    private volatile ServletContext _servletContext;
}
```

(see the rest of the project as well: There's a bnd.bnd that contains information for the `osgi.web.symbolicname` configuration, etc)

Comment: Yes, I use the Component annotation and I deploy it as OSGi bundle on my service. Anyway as I understand in Liferay 7.x version, should I create a separate portlet, where contents are displayed by JSP?

Comment: well, your sample code in the question does not contain any @Component annotation, and you explicitly mention _"use Scala and SBT, so I can't use maven or something else"_. The translation into that environment would be up to you - I can't tell you how to write declarative OSGi services in Scala (but it's certainly possible). If you want to embed your output into a page (make it part of the page), then portlets are a good option in 7.1 - in later versions remote apps (React etc) are a good option as well.

Comment: I want also ask about this: in Reference you use blade.strutsaction for symbolic name, in bnd file web-contextPath has value /bladestrutsaction. How are they related? Should the values match or are they described different things?

Comment: That looks like a bug in that sample. I'd say that they both should be identical (and for your use case: Please pick your own name)

Comment: I change implementation as you had advised in example by using request dispatcher and servlet context with using reference annotation.

SCR:INFO showed this (see next comment). It seems I can't get the servlet context.

Comment: Bundle-SymbolicName in bundle manifest is correct

Component Configuration Id: 5836
--------------------------------
State:        UNSATISFIED REFERENCE
Config Props: (4 entries)
  ServletContext.target<String> = (osgi.web.symbolicname=com.name1.name2.name3.action)
  component.id<Long> = 5836
  component.name<String> = com.name1.name2.name3.MyStrutsAction
  path<String> = /portal/content-link/open
References:   (total 1)
  - ServletContext: javax.servlet.ServletContext UNSATISFIED 1..1 static
    target=(osgi.web.symbolicname=com.name1.name2.name3.action) scope=bundle

Comment: It's not the `Bundle-SymbolicName` that you need in the `@Reference` target. It's the [`Web-ContextPath`](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-blade-samples/blob/7.1/liferay-workspace/extensions/struts-action/bnd.bnd#L3) value

Comment: Adding Web-ContextPath in OSGI header helped, now it works! Thank you for help